# How to give a user an authentication token with DRF to use in APIs based only off their username found in headers (no password)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

To reach this token generating API on the web the user will have to first authenticate with Oauth2 with their company username/password. This username is now in the header as USERINFO-cn and I can access it with
`user = request.META['USERINFO-cn']`

I want to take the username and assign that user a unique token. I've tried following the example in the [django-rest-framework documentation on generating tokens with a customized version of obtain_auth_token](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#generating-tokens). This code gives an error since `Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)` is obviously expecting more than just a username.

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
  
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      user = request.META['USERINFO-cn']
      token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
      return Response({
          'token': token.key,
          'user': user
      })
```

I know this method may be confusing but basically I want internal users at my company to be able to use other APIs without exposing their password (just a token) but I will at least be able to determine which users are calling APIs based off the token.

Comment: `token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=User.objects.get(username=user))` ? (Are you really trusting the USERINFO-cn?)

Answer (score 1):

The `get_or_create` method requires a user instance, not a username.
Apart from the concerns of @erny you need to search for the user first and pass the object then to the method:

```
User = get_user_model()
...
username = request.META['USERINFO-cn']
user = User.objects.get(username=username)
token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
...
```